# Upload values to database that came from one input separated by semicolon.

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this input,

```
<input name="tags" class="form-control" type="text" id="tags" placeholder="separate multiple tags by semi-colon ;"/>
```

for example, I typed in Apple;Mango 
then there will be two new rows to the `Tags` table, two different uuids.

here is my code for the store:

```
  foreach ($request->input('tags', ;) as $tag_val){
            $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => $tag_val
            ]);
        }
```

It will not save to the database if the tag name already exists.

I don't think my code is correct because it returns an error: `unexpected ;`

Comment: Use `explode()`: `explode(';', $request->input('tags'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 foreach (explode( ';',$request->input('tags')) as $tag_val){
            $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => $tag_val
            ]);
        }
```

You have a syntax error and make sur eto convert it into array then loop over the array.

also make sure to wrap it into the `if` to avoid the exception

```
if($request->input('tags')){
foreach (explode( ';',$request->input('tags')) as $tag_val){
            $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate([
                'name' => $tag_val
            ]);
        }
}
```

Comment: In `explode()` the delimiter is the first parameter